# How to define a string of array with compounded data

Tags: javascript

Well I know im doing wrong ...

```js
var recipient=[{}];
if (content.moderators.length != 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < content.moderators.length; i++) {
        console.log(content.moderators[i])
        recipient[i].id=content.moderators[i];
        recipient[i].status="unread";
    }
}
```

I’m getting an error :

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined

What’s the correct way ...

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a simple array `[]` then create object and push it to the array like :

```
recipient[i]= {'id':content.moderators[i], 'status': 'unread'};
```

Full code :

```
var recipient=[];
if (content.moderators.length != 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < content.moderators.length; i++) {
        recipient[i]= {'id':content.moderators[i], 'status': 'unread'};
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This should get it:

```
var recipient = [];
if (content.moderators.length != 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < content.moderators.length; i++) {
        console.log(content.moderators[i])
        recipient.push({
            id: content.moderators[i],
            status: "unread"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @pwolaq Probably something the OP is accustomed to doing due to nuances of other languages but I just modified the original code to work.  Nit-picking about what is proper when someone is asking a direct question is more of an annoyance than it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way. You need to create the object at `recipient[id]` before assigning `id` to it. Here, you'll create the object with the properties populated already

```
var recipient = [];
if (content.moderators.length != 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < content.moderators.length; i++) {
            recipient[i] = {
                id: content.moderators[i],
                status: "unread"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just updated his code with the correct expression without questioning the logic behind it :)

Answer (score 1):

if `content.moderators` is an Array

```
var recipient = moderators.map(id => ({ id, status: "unread" }))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the new object with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

> The **`map()`** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```js
var content = { moderators: ['Hank', 'Jane', 'Ann', 'Bill'] },
    recipient = content.moderators.map(function(m) {
        return { id: m, status: "unread" };
    });

console.log(recipient);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6

```js
var content = { moderators: ['Hank', 'Jane', 'Ann', 'Bill'] },
    recipient = content.moderators.map(m => ({ id: m, status: "unread" }));

console.log(recipient);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```